# IndexError when using Scrapy for absolute links

Tags: python, json, xpath, scrapy

I am scraping a webpage from Wikipedia (particularly [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2013_films) one) using a Python library called [Scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.2/). Here was the original code:

```
import scrapy
from wikipedia.items import WikipediaItem


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wiki"
    allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org/"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:2013_films',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath('//div[@id="mw-pages"]//li')
        items = []
        for title in titles:
            item = WikipediaItem()
            item["title"] = title.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            item["url"] = title.xpath("a/@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Then in the terminal, I ran `scrapy crawl wiki -o wiki.json -t json` to output the data to a JSON file. While the code worked, the links assigned to the "url" keys were all relative links. (i.e.: `{"url": ["/wiki/9_Full_Moons"], "title": ["9 Full Moons"]}`).

Instead of */wiki/9_Full_Moons*, I needed *http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9_Full_Moons*. So I modified the above mentioned code to import the **urljoin** from the urlparse library. I also modified my `for` loop to look like this instead:

```
for title in titles:
    item = WikipediaItem()
    url = title.xpath("a/@href").extract()
    item["title"] = title.xpath("a/text()").extract()
    item["url"] = urljoin("http://en.wikipedia.org", url[0])
    items.append(item)
return(items)
```

I believed this was the correct approach since the type of data assigned to the `url` key is enclosed in brackets (which would entail a list, right?) so to get the string inside it, I typed **url[0]**. However, this time I got an IndexError that looked like this:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Can someone help explain where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after mirroring the code to the example given in the documentation **[here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)**, I was able to get the code to work:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for text in response.xpath('//div[@id="mw-pages"]//li/a/text()').extract():
        yield WikipediaItem(title=text)
    for href in response.xpath('//div[@id="mw-pages"]//li/a/@href').extract():
        link = urljoin("http://en.wikipedia.org", href)
        yield WikipediaItem(url=link)
```

If anyone needs further clarification on how the **Items** class works, **[the documentation is here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html)**.

Furthermore, although the code works, it won't pair the title with its respective link. So it will give you

> TITLE, TITLE, TITLE, LINK, LINK, LINK

instead of

> TITLE, LINK, TITLE, LINK, TITLE, LINK

(the latter being probably the more desired result) — but that's for another question. If anyone has a proposed solution that works better than mine, I'll be more than happy to listen to your answers! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just concatenate the two strings instead of using `urljoin`. Try this:

```
for title in titles:
    item = WikipediaItem()
    item["title"] = title.xpath("a/text()").extract()
    item["url"] = "http://en.wikipedia.org" + title.xpath("a/@href").extract()[0]
    items.append(item)
return(items)
```

Comment: Was a nice idea but unfortunately got a type error. `item["url"] = "http://en.wikipedia.org" + title.xpath("a/@href").extract()
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`

Comment: There is one bug , you need to do as follow, item["url"] = "http://en.wikipedia.org" + title.xpath("a/@href").extract()[0]

Answer (score 0):

On your first iteration of code with relative links, you used the `xpath` method: `item["url"] = title.xpath("a/@href").extract()` 
The object returned is (I assume) a list of strings, so indexing it would be valid.

In the new iteration, you used the `select` method: `url = title.select("a/@href").extract()` Then you treated the returned object as an iterable, with `url[0]`. Check what the `select` method returns, maybe it's a list, like in the previous example.

P.S.: [IPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython) is your friend.

Comment: Oh sorry. That was my mistake. It was supposed to be `xpath` not `select`. The `select` method is deprecated and will not work.

Answer (score -1):

For better clarification, i am going to modify above code,

```
for title in titles:
    item = WikipediaItem()
    item["title"] = title.xpath("a/text()").extract()
    item["url"] = "http://en.wikipedia.org" + title.xpath("a/@href").extract()[0]
    items.append(item)
return(items)
```